# XGBClassifier error! ValueError: feature_names mismatch:

Tags: machine-learning, python, xgboost

I have a data set given as follows:
target shape `(200000, 1)`
train_data.shape `(200000, 48)`
test_data.shape`(100000, 48)`

I had used the data to `predict_proba` using `RandomForestClassifier` `ExtraTreesClassifier` `RandomForestClassifier` `AdaBoostClassifier` `GradientBoostingClassifier` and `SVC`
and got results without an error.

## BUT

`clf = XGBClassifier()` is showing following errors (with the same code except `clf`):

`ValueError: feature_names mismatch:`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem occurs due to `DMatrix..num_col()` only returning the amount of non-zero columns in a sparse matrix. Hence, if both train & test data have the same amount of non-zero columns, everything works fine. Otherwise, you end up with different feature names lists. There're currently three solutions to work around this problem:

1. realign the columns names of the train dataframe and test dataframe using:

   ```
   test_df = test_df[train_df.columns]
   ```
2. save the model first and then load the model
3. change the test data into array before feeding into the model, ie: use,

   ```
   test_df.values instead of test_df
   ```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
train_data = np.array(train_data)
test_data = np.array(test_data)
clf = XGBClassifier()
clf.fit(train,y_train.ravel())
pred = clf.predict_proba(test_data)
```

Use this instead of your original code.

Comment: Thanks I used `clf.fit(train,y_train.values.ravel())` **but still showing `ValueError: feature_names mismatch:`**
the error comes with the following:
`clf_pred = clf.predict_proba(test_data)`
is there another way to predict probabilities with `XGBClassifier()`?

Comment: check your test data shape and format. data that you provide in training time is not matching with testing time.

Comment: Does the order of the columns in `train_data` and `test_data` have to do with this **error**? I didn't get the order with other classifiers!

Comment: are you converting test_data as numpy array . like test_data = numpy.array(test_data) ???

Comment: **No.**
all are pandas dataframes with:
target shape `(200000, 1)` train_data.shape `(200000, 48)` test_data.shape `(100000, 48)`

Comment: the predict function does not take the DataFrame (or a sparse matrix) as input. convert it numpy array , then give it as input.

Comment: what `fnc` can i put (to convert `test_data`) in `clf.predict_proba(fnc(test_data))` to run it?

Comment: see modify answer.

Comment: okay lemme try this.

Comment: how come other classifiers didn't put up this error for `clf.predict_proba`?

Comment: is it now working with you ???

Comment: see my answer below. I used ordered columns to get rid of the mismatch.
sorry didn't try `np.array()`
btw it looks like its taking a dataframe in `predict_proba()`

Answer (score 2):

i used this to resolve the issue.
as the order of the columns in dataframe were not same.

`train_data.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
test_data.sort_index(axis=1,inplace=True)`